# Is possible generate an Excel file with charts based on XML?

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, ms-office

I have a big problem trying to find some library to help me in my project to generate excel files with charts attached, and I think it's a better option to use an XML file to achieve this task, but I can't find any example or guideline to form an XML or XSL for an excel file with a chart, so any help or different suggestion to tackle this, is welcome.

Comment: Start by creating an Excel file with charts that mimics what you are trying to do. Save that file as an .XLSX file. Rename it to ".zip" and unzip it ... and XLSX is merely a zip container. investigate all the things inside which will be a bunch of XML files and directories to see how they are constructed. Or you can use the "Save as XML" option for a singular view.

Comment: Have you reviewed http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/ ?

Comment: Have you thought about Google Charts/Google Docs? Failing that something like D3...https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery. And JSON is far easier to work with. Also may be worth looking at Python/R.